# Gallery and Fancybox

Tags: php, html, fancybox, modx, modx-revolution

I am using the Gallery Snippet on `MODx` Revolution 2.1.5.

I am calling out the basic Gallery Snippet along with the specified Album.

I am trying to link `Fancybox` (jQuery Lightbox) up to the Thumbnails and images.

This is what MODx Outputs on the Resource:

```
<div class="gal-item"> 
<a href="path/to/page/test.html?galItem=1&galAlbum=1&galTag="> 
<img class="" src="/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&w=100&h=100&zc=1&far=C&q=90&src=%2Fassets%2Fcomponents%2Fgallery%2Ffiles%2F1%2F4.jpg" alt="lorem-ipsum-2.jpg" /> 
</a> 
</div>
```

I have selected the content correctly, When I click on the image wrapped in the link tag I get this message:

The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.

How can it not be loaded? It's loading the Thumbnail and it needs the original image to create the Thumbnail. How can it not find the image?

Note: I am using the default setup for this Add-on.

Thank you!

Comment: what is your url to your big image (which is in Popup) ? This one "path/to/page/test.html?galItem=1&galAlbum=1&galTag="  ..    ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AlexC has mentioned I reckon it's to do with your big image path.  Have you tried going to that URL direct and seeing if the image loads.  You could trying removing the fancybox code and then click on the thumb and see if the link works as normal. The image should load on it's own in the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

I can be am lots of causes why id does like that.

I think what it can be, you try to load content before you have this guy, I mean use some Ajax and it loads after you apply the  "fancybox"

you can try this :

1. remove the "fancybox" classname
2. and use this code :

   ```
   $(".gal-item").live("click", function(){
       var $href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

       var $href = $(this).attr("href");


       $.fancybox({
          href:$href
       });
   ```

   });